# TypeError: string indices must be integers. While using dataframe

Tags: dataframe, output, typeerror, prediction, stockquotes

I am just simply getting a stock quote for AAPL using df and I am getting this error. Can someone help me in this matter. I am new to python.

```
#Get the Stock quote
df = web.DataReader('AAPL', data_source= 'yahoo' , start= 2012-0o1-0o1 , end= 2023-0o4-0o5)
#Show the data
df[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChuFi.png)
```

I tried to get the stock quote for AAPL for stock price prediction project. I expected the snippet to generate an output of the list of prices from a given start date to end date. Then this error popped up.